# Query antivirus product in Windows servers, where SecurityCenter2 namespace is not available

Tags: windows, wmic, antivirus

On workstations like Windows 7 I use the following command to query AV:

```
WMIC /Node:localhost /Namespace:\\root\SecurityCenter2 Path AntiVirusProduct Get displayName /Format:List
```

But on Windows Server 2012, the SecurityCenter2 namespace is not available.

What is the possible alternative on servers?

Comment: You can take a look at [How can I determine whether an Antivirus product is installed?](https://serverfault.com/questions/12343/how-can-i-determine-whether-an-antivirus-product-is-installed)